# initialising vector of pointers for a user defined class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I tried to initialize a vector of pointers but got some error, both code and the errors are below

```
class tr
{
public:
    int n = 26;
    vector<tr* >  a(n  ,NULL);

};
```

the error I got is :

```
try_class.cpp:7:25: error: ‘n’ is not a type
        vector<tr* >  a(n  ,NULL);
                        ^
try_class.cpp:7:29: error: expected identifier before ‘__null’
        vector<tr* >  a(n  ,NULL);
                            ^~~~
try_class.cpp:7:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘__null’
```

I could not figure out what is wrong with my code

Comment: You can't use parentheses when initializing members inline in a class, as that will be used to declare functions. Use either "assignment" syntax (like you do with `n`) or use curly-braces `{}` (which will not be possible in your case with `std::vector`). Or as an alternative, create a constructor and initialize the vector in the constructors member initializer list.

Comment: On a slightly related note, the recommended "null pointer" is [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) or plain `0`. And for pointers that's the default value so you don't need to specify it at all when initializing the vector, only the size.

Comment: A class which contains itself a container with pointers to its own... ...sounds like a tree. To me it seems you could use `std::array` instead of `std::vector` in this case.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Maybe using a vector is wrong in the first place.

Comment: What is `n` used for more than as the size of the vector? Do you really need it as a separate member variable? Perhaps it should be `static`? Perhaps it should be `const` or `constexpr`?

Answer (score 2):

Parents are not allowed for member initialization (to avoid most vexing parse issue).

You might do instead:

```
class tr
{
public:
    int n = 26;
    std::vector<tr*>  a{std::size_t(n), nullptr};
};
```

or

```
class tr
{
public:
    int n = 26;
    std::vector<tr*> a = std::vector<tr*>(n, nullptr);
};
```

Comment: `{std::size_t(n), nullptr}` doesn't match `initializer_list<tr*>`, so we are good. `std::vector<std::size_t>` would be problematic though.